# Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring

Tags: spring, hibernate-mapping

when i start the tomcat , i have this log to my console

- Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
- Building new Hibernate SessionFactory

I making the more research , i don't win the good answer , somme body can help me?

thank

The structure of my apply are: Jsp, hibernate, spring, oracle 11g, tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) and [`<mvc:annotation-driven />`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable), your app will pick up Hibernate Validator if it can be found on the classpath. Since it doesn't find it, download the Hibernate Validator jar and place it on the classpath (better yet: reference it through a build tool like maven). Then it should work "automatically".